# ActiveRecord::Relation, any way to remove existing limit and offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming I have a `User` model

```
paged_users = User.scoped.limit(2).offset(3)
```

Is there a way to make `paged_user` have `User.scoped` by removing limit and offset? IE:

```
all_user = paged_users.remove_limit.remove_offset
```

Comment: "User.scoped.limit(2).offset(2).limit(100000).offset(0)"  I can add 1M limit and 0 offset, but looking for alternative.

Comment: Please format your code in your questions by using four-space indenting. Also: there is no need to sign your messages.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm thinking you have a scope like this:

```
users = User.where("something").limit(20).order("name ASC")
```

With this in mind...

To remove the `limit` pass `nil` to `limit`:

```
users.limit(nil)
```

Then to remove the ordering, use `reorder`, also passing it `nil`:

```
users.limit(nil).reorder(nil)
```

That will remove both the limit and the order from your scope, preserving all other things. If you were to use `unscoped`, it would remove *all* scoping.

Comment: As an addition to the answer, you can also remove offset `users.unscope(:offset)`
in general unscope accepts arguments what to unscope and there are 


`VALID_UNSCOPING_VALUES = Set.new([:where, :select, :group, :order, :lock, :limit, :offset, :joins, :left_outer_joins, :annotate, :includes, :from, :readonly, :having, :optimizer_hints])
`